# In laravel i can show the product name, how to show it in vue.js

Tags: json, laravel, vue.js

This is the view route

```
 public function showOrder(Order $order)
    {      
        return view('return.sales-return-show', compact('order'));
    }
```

This is output for dd($order);

```
  #original: array:18 [▼
    "id" => 7
    "company_id" => 1
    "order_type" => 1
    "order_no" => "12"
    "date" => "2019-01-16"
    "status" => "1"
    "transaction_raw" => "[{"amount":"82264","transaction_type":3,"payment_type":1,"owner_type":"App\\Model\\Customer","owner_id":"1"},{"amount":"0","transaction_type":4,"payment_type":1 ▶"
    "line_items" => "[{"customer_id":"1","product_id":"10","unit_id":"2","quantity":"5","price":"2700","total_price":"13500"},{"customer_id":"1","product_id":"43","unit_id":"1","quantity":"52","price":"7","total_price":"364"},{"customer_id":"1","product_id":"9","unit_id":"2","quantity":"18","price":"3800","total_price":"68400"}] ◀"
    "total" => 82264.0
    "discount" => 0.0
    "sub_total" => 82264.0
    "paid" => 0.0
    "due" => 82264.0
    "supplier_id" => 0
    "customer_id" => 1
    "others_fin" => "{"transport":"0","type":"income"}"
    "created_at" => "2019-01-16 19:13:27"
    "updated_at" => "2019-01-16 19:13:27"
  ]
```

This is the loop where I can show the product name

```
@foreach($order->items as $item)
   {{$item->product->name}}
@endforeach
```

This is my json route

```
public function json(Order $order)
{
   return response()->json(['orders' => $order]);
}
```

JSON Data:

{
   "orders":{
      "id":7,
      "company_id":1,
      "order_type":1,
      "order_no":"12",
      "date":"2019-01-16",
      "status":"1",
      "transaction_raw":[
         {
            "amount":"82264",
            "transaction_type":3,
            "payment_type":1,
            "owner_type":"App\Model\Customer",
            "owner_id":"1"
         },
         {
            "amount":"0",
            "transaction_type":4,
            "payment_type":1,
            "owner_type":"App\Model\Customer",
            "owner_id":"1",
            "account_head_id":1
         }
      ],
      "line_items":[
         {
            "customer_id":"1",
            "product_id":"10",
            "unit_id":"2",
            "quantity":"5",
            "price":"2700",
            "total_price":"13500"
         },
         {
            "customer_id":"1",
            "product_id":"43",
            "unit_id":"1",
            "quantity":"52",
            "price":"7",
            "total_price":"364"
         },
         {
            "customer_id":"1",
            "product_id":"9",
            "unit_id":"2",
            "quantity":"18",
            "price":"3800",
            "total_price":"68400"
         }
      ],
      "total":82264,
      "discount":0,
      "sub_total":82264,
      "paid":0,
      "due":82264,
      "supplier_id":0,
      "customer_id":1,
      "others_fin":"{\"transport\":\"0\",\"type\":\"income\"}",
      "created_at":"2019-01-16 19:13:27",
      "updated_at":"2019-01-16 19:13:27"
   }
}

Now I need to show PRODUCT NAME here

```
<tr v-for="order in orders.line_items">
 <td></td>
 <td><input name="" v-model="PRODUCT NAME" class="form-control"></td>
 <td>{{order.product_id}}</td>
 <td></td>
 <td><input name="" v-model="order.quantity" class="form-control"></td>
 <td><input name="" v-model="order.price" class="form-control" disabled></td>
 <td><input name="" v-model="order.quantity * order.price" class="form-control" disabled></td>
 <td></td>
</tr>
```

How to do it...?

Comment: Please, improve the details of your question so we can understand what are you trying to achieve. If you need help in this regard, check this article: [ask]

Comment: Please show the code you've tried and explain how it didn't work.  We can not troubleshoot a problem that was not presented.

Answer (score 0):

It seems your product name is missing in JSON you provided. As far as I see, your product is related with entity "line_item". You need to "eager load" your product with your "line_item"

Change your json action to this:

```
public function json($id)
{
    $order = Order::with(['items', 'items.product'])
        ->where('id', $id)
        ->first();
    return response()->json(['order' => $order]);
}
```

And then in your vue template:

```
<tr v-for="order_item in order.items">
 <td></td>
 <td><input name="" v-model="order_item.product.name" class="form-control" type="text"></td>
 <td>{{order_item.product_id}}</td>
 <td></td>
 <td><input name="" v-model="order_item.quantity" class="form-control" type="text"></td>
 <td><input name="" v-model="order_item.price" class="form-control" disabled type="text"></td>
 <td><input name="" v-model="order_item.quantity * order_item.price" class="form-control" disabled type="text"></td>
 <td></td>
</tr>
```

I am not sure that code will work as it is, but the main idea is to "eager load" order lines ("line_items") and products with your object of order, which you get by id in your json action. After that, you iterate through order lines in your vue template.

Comment: **$order = Order::with(['items', 'items.product'])** what is passing here as items and items.product?

Comment: That means "eager loading" and "nested eager loading": https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading . Do you get the product info in your JSON now? If not, describe me relations between order, order item and product.

Comment: So did you solve your problem? We need your response :)

Answer (score 0):

Yea, the problem is solved now.

This is my json data below

```
public function json(Order $order)
    {
        $products = $order->line_items;
        $productIds = array_column($products, 'product_id');
        $orderedProducts = Product::whereIn('id', $productIds)->get()->groupBy('id');
        return response()->json(['orders' => $order, 'orderedProducts' =>$orderedProducts->toArray() ]);
    }
```

And this is AdReturn.vue

```
<tr v-for="order in orders.line_items">
  <td><input name="" v-model="orderedProducts[order.product_id][0].name" class="form-control" disabled></td>
  <td><input name="" v-model="order.quantity" class="form-control"></td>
  <td><input name="" v-model="order.price" class="form-control" disabled></td>
  <td><input name="" v-model="order.quantity * order.price" class="form-control" disabled></td>
</tr>
```